When does a SQL Agent command-line job step actually write records to sysjobhistory?
Consider a SQL Agent job which runs a long-running Operating system (CmdExec) step, where the advanced option to include step output in history is checked/enabled.  In principle, anything that the executable in the step command emits to its standard output is captured and written to one or more records in the msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory table.
However, for some executables, this results in one sysjobhistory record containing a lot of text and, for other executables, it results in multiple records each containing a fragment of the text, and it does not appear (at least to me) consistent or predicatable as to when the Agent will will emit a new record.
For instance, given a log-shipping restore job (i.e. a CmdExec step calling sqllogship.exe) that is running after a period of suspension, I often see a record with some preamble, then a record for each logged file skipped or restored; some of these records may contain the text of multiple logged entries.
In another case, for a custom-written executable, I might see all of the output in one record, or it might split it into multiple records.  Similarly, invoking a batch file which itself calls a number of commands may emit a record per command, or combine output into a single record.  Robocopy.exe is a classic – it may write multiple "New file" log entries to a single record, or may split them; and, if you happen not to pass /np, can write its progress percentage across multiple records.
The documentation for sysjobhistory says...

In most cases, the data is updated only after the job step completes, and the table typically contains no records for job steps that are currently in progress. In some cases, underlying processes do provide information about in progress job steps.

So, in practical terms, how does one craft a process which would "provide information about in progress job steps"?  Is there something specific in the output that the Agent is looking for to coerce it to emit a new record?  It doesn't seem to length or time based, nor does it seem to be specifically sensitive to line-endings.
(Note that I'm not looking for an alternative way of logging my step output here – writing to a log file or a dedicated table is trivial.  I am more-interested this specific function of the SQL Agent.)


However, for some executables, this results in one sysjobhistory record containing a lot of text and, for other executables, it results in multiple records each containing a fragment of the text [...]

This depends upon the application and framework used, mostly due to the nuances around how and when standard output and standard error buffers are flushed. The writing of the records depends on there being output available (otherwise nothing will be logged as there is no output), and output is generally only available once it has been flushed. Most frameworks (.net, C++, etc.) give the programmer control over how this works depending on the calls made.

So, in practical terms, how does one craft a process which would "provide information about in progress job steps"?

The easiest way is to make your logging in the executable either emit information that needs to all be together, together before flushing or emit the information in a way that is intelligible without needing other context.
